# How does Android export project in Eclipse work?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

How does the Export feature of Eclipse work in Android Project. Does it totally compile the code in some mode or does it just takes the previously compiled apk which was run for emulator. Signs it and then reanmes it gives it to the user?

Edit: When using AppEngine Connected Android Project, the exported apk works differently if I have not debugged it in "Remote AppEngine" and only in "Local AppEngine" mode compared to an export that was done after a debug in "Remote AppEngine" Mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does it totally compile the code in some mode?**
Yes, It compiles the apk from the path that you provided. As if the code was being compiled for the first time.

**does it just takes the previously compiled apk which was run for emulator?**
No. It would never take copy the one from the emulator to give it back to you.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles the code in an apk file signed by a specific key that you created.

Comment: Question is: **Does it totally compile the code in some mode or does it just takes the previously compiled apk which was run for emulator.**, please check it before answering

Answer (score 0):

Its a fresh compilation of the saved code